# Socket programming error

Tags: php

When I am running my program of socket I am getting an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create() in C:\wamp\www\sockert\sockert.php on line 11

What about that error?

---

Code:

```
// set some variables
$host = "192.168.1.99";
$port = 1234;
// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
```

I am using php5.3.0

Comment: Please post the code that causes the error.  Also, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: // set some variables
$host = "192.168.1.99";
$port = 1234;

// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);

// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
...
...
I am using  php5.3.0

Answer (score 1):

The `sockets` extension is not activated.

You should load `php_sockets.dll` in php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

In the file `php.ini` file, find the line with `php_sockets.dll` and remove the leading semi colon (`;`)

Comment: I did it. I remove the ; from my extension and just download and place php_sockets.dll in dll directory where all supporting dll are kept. but still getting this error.

Comment: Now this is running i was changed in php instead of apache. this is enabled now.thanks

Answer (score 0):

The functions staring with `socket_` are not activated by default in PHP. But there exists a better alternative anyways: the `stream` extension offers support for sockets too, and this is available regardless of your PHP and platform, and is also much more easy to use.

I've written a blog post explaining Stream Sockets here: http://www.christophh.net/2012/07/24/php-socket-programming/

I hope this helps.